# react native memory leak while using navigation within promise

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am facing memory leak issue when I navigate from one screen through other using promise.

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userInfo: null,
        };
        this.checklogin();
    }
```

Here is my checklogin function

```
    checklogin() {
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
            getData().then((user) => {
                if(user) {
navigate('dashboard');
                    return;
                } else {
                    this.setState({login: false});
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // alert(error.message);
            });
        }
```

And here is my async storage

```
export async function getData() {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        if (value !== null) {
            return JSON.parse(value);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why are you calling `navigate(navigate('dashboard'))` instead of `navigate('dashboard')`? Also I don't know if it's a good idea to call `setState` inside your constructor

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak sorry that was typo error while modifying to post here

Comment: hm well in that case I'd change your logic so that you're not setting state in the constructor. Either default your state to `false` and just don't update it or run `this.checkLogin` in `componentDidMount`. If you want to prevent rendering use a loading flag